# Perform Self Join & Aggregation On Panda DataFrame, & Spark Scala ,Python Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Join Two Data Frames,

**Team , Captain, Match_ID**

```
A,      Jack,   13 
A,      Jack,   14
A,      Sam,    15 
B,      Nancy,  13
B,      Rob,    14
B,      Job,    15
```

**Team_L , Team_R , Match_ID,Match_Date, Winning Team**

```
A           B       13      12011018    A
A           B       15      13011018    B
```

Output DataFrame must have,
**Team_L , Team_R , Match_ID,Match_Date, Winning Team,**

and the **6**  additional fields,  **WinRationOfTeam_L** , **WinRationOfTeam_R**, 
 **WinRationOfTeam_L_VS_R** ,  **WinRationOfCaptain_L**, **WinRationOfCaptain_R**, **WinRatio_Captain_L_VS_R**

Let Say ,

- **WinRationOfTeam_L** Team L Played 15 matches with *any*, and won 10 then Team A win Ration is 10/15

  - **WinRationOfCaptain_L** Team L  with 'Jack ? '  as captain Played 4 matches  with *any*, and won 1 then Team A win Ration is 1/4 = 0.25
  - **WinRationOfTeam_L_VS_R** Team A Played 5 matches *with Team R*, and won 3 then Team A win Ration is 3/4 = 0.75
  - **WinRatio_Captain_L_ON_R** Team A played 3 *with Captain Jack played with Team B with Rob as Captain* ,  and won 2 then WinRatio_Captain_L_ON_R =2/3 =0.66

To Give a perspective, Country A Football team, won 85 out of 100 matches,
winRatio is 0.85
Dan as the captain for Team_A and played 20 matches, and won 10 out of 20.
WinRtion of Captain is 10/20 which is 0.5.

Team A played with Team B 10 times, Team A won 6 , Now if Team A is in the output dataframe under column Team_L, then WinRationOfTeam_L_VS_R is 6/10 =0.6

Dan as the captain for Team_A and played 4 with Jim as captain of Team B, and won 3.
Then
WinRatio_Captain_L_VS_R is 3/4 = 0.75